# Calculated Column - Days Difference - Syntax Error

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula, date-time

I have a SharePoint List and I'd like to have a column to calculate the days it take to solve a ticket (Solution date - Submission Date).

I tried to create a calculated column, by using a formula `= DATEDIF([Submission Date],[Solution Date],"D")`, and return data with "Number". It didn't allow me to create this as it says Syntax error.

I researched and tried to replaced "," with ";" `= DATEDIF([Submission Date];[Solution Date];"D")` , still didn't work.

Both Solution date & Submission Date columns are formatted as "Date and Time" Type.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
=DATEDIF([Solution Date], [Submission Date], "d")
```

[Calculate the difference between two dates](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/bb862071(v=office.14)#calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates)

Comment: Hello, still doesn't work - "The formula contains a syntax error or is not supported.".

Comment: Try creating a new list in your SharePoint site, add two date columns and use this formula. just to make sure if there is any issue with the current SP list.

Comment: I tried to do it in another sharepoint and it worked. Now i wonder if the setting of this particular sharepoint has disabled the "Calculated Column" Function.. anyone knows where to check?

Comment: I think there is no such setting to disable creating calculated column in list. Have you tried it in another SharePoint site or another SharePoint list?

Comment: @Kiki I don’t think it is possible to disable calculated column function in SharePoint. Can you use another formula in this list like “=INT([Submission Date]-[Solution Date])”?

Comment: @GaneshSanap I tried in another SP Site, and it worked; but when i tried another SP List in the original SP Site, it didn't work. The SP i wanted to build the list in is a "Private Group", does it matter?

Comment: @Chelsea_MSFT I tried your suggested formula, still doesn't work. The error changed to "The formula refers to a column that does not exist.  Check the formula for spelling mistakes or change the non-existing column to an existing column.".

Comment: @Kiki This error suggests that there might be a typo in the column name. Do not copy the formula I provide but use the "Insert Column" and "Add to formula" on the right. See if you can get rid of the error. ps. It doesn't matter if the site is in a "Private Group".

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
=DATA.DIFF([Travel start date];[Travel end date];"D")
```